# Why does a negative NSInteger (long) value become garbage when sent through variadic arguments?

Tags: objective-c, c, variadic-functions

I've created a C function with variadic arguments (NSIntegers) like below:

```
NSInteger test(NSInteger arg, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, arg);
    NSInteger arg2 = va_arg(args, NSInteger);
    return arg + arg2;
}
```

On calling this function with negative second value, it somehow becomes a very large number.

```
test( 2,  2); // result = 4
test(-2,  2); // result = 0
test( 2, -2); // result = 4294967296
```

However, if I use int instead of NSInteger for the variadic argument, everything works as expected.

```
NSInteger test2(NSInteger arg, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, arg);
    int arg2 = va_arg(args, int);
    return arg + arg2;
}
```

Tests:

```
test2( 2,  2); // result = 4
test2(-2,  2); // result = 0
test2( 2, -2); // result = 0
```

Anything I'm probably missing here or doing something wrong? Would be great if someone can point me in the right direction here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're passing integer literals as the arguments, so in the case of `2` and `-2`, these will be passed as `int`s.  So you're invoking undefined behaviour by trying to read an `NSInteger`.

To solve this, use an explicit cast:

```
test(2, (NSInteger)-2);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. `-2l` works as well. Guess I need to have a better understanding of how C works underneath.

Comment: @Himanshu I can only confirm this. I always advise everybody trying to do OS X or iOS programming to master C before getting into Objective-C and Cocoa (else nasal demons and headache will be present).

Comment: @Himanshu: That isn't portable though.  As I understand, `NSInteger` may be a typedef for either `int` or `long`; on a platform where it's `int`, using `-2l` will cause an equivalent problem.